# Clearing the images , when new function called in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload, angular-file-upload

I have list of images and I had set my `imageStorysource` as the first file from response.

JS:

```
   scope.previewImage( element[0].files[0] ); 

        $scope.previewImage = function ( file ) {
        fileReader.readAsDataUrl( file, $scope)
        .then(function(result) {
            $scope.file        = file;
            $scope.imageStorysource = result;
        });
    };
```

I want to clear this image when I call a new model, but the values are not clearing. I tried giving `$scope.imageStorysource = "";` but it is not clearing. Need assistance.

Comment: it would be good if you can provide link of working demo over jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: that's because ng-src already compiles the image `src` to `$scope.imageStorysource`; changing the `ng-src` wouldn't have any effect on the image `src` as it is already generated. You should use a directive to change the image `src`

Comment: google for `reset input type file`, should lead you to answer